# Jboss 5.1 GA Automatic Shutdown

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, agents-jade

I have deployed my application on Jboss 5.1 GA. In my application I am using only one RestFul web service and JADE components.

I am running 2 jboss servers on base linux machine.

1) Jboss 4.0.1 on 8080 port

2) Jboss 5.1 GA on 8280 port

After few days my Jboss 5.1 GA server shutdown automatically, log says shutdown hook called... I have checked all logs and found following -

2011-09-08 00:42:46,683 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] (JBoss Shutdown Hook) Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true

There is nothing which will explain why jboss shutdown hook called?

Also checked my code for `System.exit();` and tried to start jboss server as daemon in linux but, problem continues...

So why jboss server is calling its shutdown hook?

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: Did the solution below solve your problem? I am facing same issue on my server as well.

Comment: No still facing same problem :(

Comment: hmm, I am going to try -Xrs in JAVA_OPTS (Found it on jboss community), did you try that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you used the official script to start the JBoss, then exited the terminal without the command "exit".

> /etc/init.d/jboss start

Mostly, we don't suspect these scripts which from JBoss itself, but actually some of them are not trustworthy.
To avoid the HUP(hang up) signal, we should use "nohup" ahead:

> nohup /etc/init.d/jboss start

Comment: @Yogesh: Did this solve your problem? I am facing same issue on my server as well.